# Ускорение работы сайта при большом файле стилей

Tags: css, wordpress, pagespeed-insights

Достался мне сайт на WordPress для ускорения(до этого с ним работал не я). На каждой странице происходит подгрузка 3-4 файлов стилей 2 с которых повторяются. Один с них подключается в теге  и имеет адекватный для данного сайта размер. Второй файл перед футером и он просто гигант 37000 строк и 1,3Мб объем. Если с первым я еще понимаю что делать, то второй меня вводит в ступор. Как поступить в данной ситуации? Ну или как поступили бы Вы?

Comment: Сжатие, кеширование. Что еще тут можно придумать. Ну а так-то вообще ничего особенного. Общий объем css для среднего сайта переваливает за 100 тыс строк

Comment: Такой огромный css это конечно же ужас. Стоит разобраться откуда он берётся и избавиться от этого.

Comment: @SeVlad да ну чего ты. Я помню, как сам накидал 8000 строк (половина из них анимация) для лэндинга на wp. То есть я не очень приветствовал такой дизайн, но не от меня зависело. А где 8000 для главной, там и 30000 для остального)))

Comment: @KAGGDesign Для основной разметки используется Bootstrap и часть данных стилей еще и дублируется в других файлах. Складывается впечатление, что половина этого файла прям бесполезна.

Comment: Можно разбираться по каждой странице в отдельности, потом все сводить в кучу. Например, такое средство есть https://unused-css.com/ А можно и забить. Сколько сайт грузится по Pingdom и сколько времени уходит на css?

Comment: @Alex Bryk вы спрашиваете: "Ну или как поступили бы Вы?". Я бы применил или https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp или же https://ampstart.com/templates ++ https://ampbyexample.com/ - в зависимости от сложности / тематики веб-сайта.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Как не странно Pingdom дает лучшие показатели чем GoogleDevTools. На Pingdom около 4 секунд грузится сайт и этот файл 300мс, но на GDevTools этот файл грузится 900мс.

Comment: @Alex Bryk прочитайте эту статью о разных измерителях скорости загрузки вебсайта https://gtmetrix.com/blog/the-difference-between-gtmetrix-pagespeed-insights-pingdom-tools-and-webpagetest/

Comment: 4 сек - это очень долго. Вы сначала оптимизируйте все остальное, а потом уж отлавливайте остаток в 300мс.

Comment: @nikant25 Спасибо, обязательно прочту!

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо! Так и сделаю.

Comment: @KAGGDesign не хочу тут развивать трёп (тупо не удобно), но 1,3 метра - это ппц как дохрена. Ну если только для какой-то специфической задачи, Я стараюсь чтобы вся морда была в 200-300кб. Ну иногда до 700, если графики на 600. Но выше метра - это ахтунг.

Comment: @SeVlad не, ну а что ТС делать? Сайт переписывать? Думаю, бюджета на это нет

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну я ж не знаю какие условия у ТС. Я написал что нужно бы сделать. А если нет бюджета/желания... Я бы лично не брался если этого нет. :)